# Refresh BigQuery data in Sheets via an API call

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

Given a Google Sheet which has data coming from BigQuery via the *Sheets data connector for BigQuery* (as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/connecting-bigquery-and-google-sheets-to-help-with-hefty-data-analysis)), is it possible to force a refresh of this BigQuery data via the Sheets API? It is possible to do so through the Sheets UI (has a refresh button), but I want to do it via some other service invoking an API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apps Script to interact with the data connector in your Spreadsheet.

### Considerations

From the Sheet API you are not able to manipulate the DataSource. You can use Apps Script instead. It's relatively easy to set up a script that refreshes you BigQuery data.

### Approach

If you want to do this operation with an external API you will have to use Apps Script as a proxy to achieve your goal. You can deploy your Apps Script as a **API Executable** and trigger its functions from an external service.

#### Apps Script

```js
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function refresh() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Data Sheet 1'), true);
  SpreadsheetApp.enableAllDataSourcesExecution();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getDataSourceTables()[0].refreshData();
};
```

#### Your External Service

```java
// [...] Oauth and other set ups...

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // ID of the script to call. Acquire this from the Apps Script editor,
    // under Publish > Deploy as API executable.
    String scriptId = "ENTER_YOUR_SCRIPT_ID_HERE";
    Script service = getScriptService();

    // Create an execution request object.
    ExecutionRequest request = new ExecutionRequest()
            .setFunction("refresh");

    try {
        // Make the API request.
        Operation op =
                service.scripts().run(scriptId, request).execute();

// [...] Error handling...
```

### Refrences:

[Big Query data connector](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/02/refresh-bigquery-data-sheets.html)

[Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute)